# AspNetCore testing with TestHost, WebApplicationTestFixture class not found

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I understand that AspNetCore 2.1 is still in release candidate form and that new testing model with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing` is not stabilized.

But I'm trying to follow examples and use `WebApplicationTestFixture` class for testing. Here is code I have so far:

```
public class UnitTest1 : IClassFixture<WebApplicationTestFixture<Startup>>
{
    public UnitTest1(WebApplicationTestFixture<Startup> fixture)
    {
        Client = fixture.CreateClient();
    }

    public HttpClient Client { get; }

    [Fact]
    public async void Test1()
    {
        var response = await Client.GetAsync("api/values");

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
```

However, I can't find `WebApplicationTestFixture` class in package anywhere. Is it located in additional assembly? Or I'm supposed to create this class?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems that during stabilization they've renamed this class. It is now named `WebApplicationFactory`.